# Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required by MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was trying to use MinMax scaler on multiple data frames using the following code.

```
for file in glob.glob('*csv'):
    name = check_output(['basename',file,'.csv']).decode().strip()
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    df[['col']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['col']])
```

But it was throwing the following error

```
Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required by MinMaxScaler
```

Comment: What is `df.shape` prior to trying to fit the scaler?

Comment: That is not true based on the error, in your loop print `df.shape` so you can figure out the file that is causing the issue.

Comment: df.shape is (4726, 2)

Comment: Yeah after looping shape is (4726, 2). Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Currently your data is missing to reproduce your issue.